# Algebra behind the wave function properties

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

In lecture, for the tunnelling wave function

$$ \psi(x) = C_1\cosh(x/l)+C_2\sinh(x/l)$$

the current density  is

$$ J = h/(2mi) [ \psi^*(\Delta\psi) - (\Delta\psi)^*\psi]  $$

Here is my problem, lecture says that $J$ is equivalent to:

$$J=(h/m)Im[\psi^*(\Delta\psi)] \tag{1} $$

and

$$J={h/(ml)}Im[C_1^*C_2] \tag{2} $$

What is the algebra behind the equation (1) and (2)?  How they was derived (especially equation (2))?

Comment: What work have you tried? do you know how to manipulate hyperbolic trig functions? If not, now is a good time to research them.

Answer (score 1):

First, your expression for the current is incorrect. It should be $\nabla$ everywhere, not $\Delta$ (first derivative, not second).

To derive (1), you just use the formula $Im(z)=\frac{z-z^*}{2 i}$ for a complex $z$.

As for (2), you just substitute the expression for the wave function into (1) and evaluate for $x=0$.

I did not check all the coefficients.